# In Sketch Is it possible to select only one anchor point on a line, so that i can adjust the end shape of one end different from the other end?

Tags: sketch-app

Using Sketch app.  In Sketch is it possible to select only one anchor point on the end of the line, so that i can adjust the end shape (rounded or square) of one end to make it different to the other end...so one end is rounded and the other is squared?

thanks

Comment: Usually in vector software the end cap attribute applies to the whole stroke (aka "border" in Sketch), not on an individual anchor basis.  I'm not a Sketch user so I'm not totally familiar with all the options, although I did take a quick look at the documentation for the border options but it doesn't look like it would be possible.  In other software such as Inkscape (which is free), I'd just use [a rounded end or start marker](https://imgur.com/71TiHEn) like adding an arrowhead marker. Hoping a sketch user will add something more useful for you here. Perhaps a plugin or something?